# Combining MSSQL results with Oracle into CFSPREADSHEET

Tags: sql-server, oracle, coldfusion

I have a report that generates an excel file daily with data extracted from a MS-SQL database. I now have to add additional columns to my spreadsheet from an Oracle database where the ID matches the ID in the MS-SQL query results.

My problem is that I have about 1200-1400+ unique IDs generated on this report from the first query. When I plug them into an IN list with the Oracle query and try to do a CFDUMP to see if the results will come out as it should, I receive a CF error saying that query cannot list more than 1000 results from the oracle query.

I basically set the values from the first query into a valuelist for the ID column and then put that into the IN clause for the Oracle query. I then do a cfdump on the Oracle where I receive that error. I've also tried wrapping cfloop query = "firstquery"> around the Oracle query and just placing #firstquery.columnIDname# but that does not work either.

So two questions I have here is ..

1. How do I handle the limit on Oracle with 1k limit and if I only have read only access to the Oracle database with ColdFusion?
2. After #1 is figured out, how could I combine the results from the Oracle Query with my MSSQL query or in other words, add the columns I'm pulling from the Oracle query to the spreadsheet for the matching ID.

Thanks.

Comment: For 2nd question i think you can fetch the data from oracle and MSSQL and using QoQ you can perform a join and fetch the desired result. For more info see this link http://help.adobe.com/en_US/ColdFusion/9.0/Developing/WSc3ff6d0ea77859461172e0811cbec0e4fd-7ff0.html

Comment: Can you not connect the two DBs, and do asrk this @ DB level? NB: the 1000 item limit on an IN() clause is *per clause*, so you could just split your IDs into separate IN() clauses. But you should do this Surry of thing on the DB, not on the CFML server if poss.

Comment: I think the best approach is to set up a linked server to oracle on your microsoft server and write a stored proc that does all that data stuff.

Comment: I know I should do on DB, but for a quick and dirty approach now, how exactly would I split up list of ids from a column from another query and dynamically insert them into two IN clauses on the oracle query?

Comment: This is similar to this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19213814/select-in-on-more-than-2100-values

Answer (score 0):

For your quick, dirty, and sub-optimal approach, visit cflib.org and look for a function called ListSplit().  It converts a long list to an array of short lists.

You then loop through this array and run a query each time.  Make sure the query name changes with each loop iteration.

After the loop, do a query of queries union query.  Then do whatever you have to do to combine that data with what you got from sql server.

Note that you will probably have to use array notation to access your dynamically named query objects.