# Pass List of Integers to Stored Procedure

Tags: sql-server, coldfusion

Here is my stored procedure:

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[Dan] 
@numbers varchar(10)    
AS
BEGIN
SET NOCOUNT ON;
select @numbers numbers
END
```

In SSMS, I can execute it successfully like this:

```
exec dbo.Dan '1.2'
```

In ColdFusion, I can execute it successfully with either of these two sets of commands:

```
<cfstoredproc procedure="dbo.dan" datasource="ClinicalDataDev">
<cfprocparam cfsqltype="cf_sql_varchar" value="1,2"> 
<cfprocresult name="abc">
</cfstoredproc>

<cfquery name="abcd" datasource="ClinicalDataDev">
exec dbo.Dan <cfqueryparam cfsqltype="cf_sql_varchar" value='1,2' list="no">
</cfquery>
```

However, I'm looking to improve on this by specifying the value as a list of integers.  Since cfprocparam does not have a list attribute, I think I am restricted to the cfquery approach.  My efforts and results so far are:

```
<cfqueryparam cfsqltype="cf_sql_integer" value='1' list="no">
executes successfully.  The purpose is to see if the procedure accepts an 
integer - it does.

<cfqueryparam cfsqltype="cf_sql_integer" value='1,2' list="no">
also executes sucessfully, but returns a value of 42006.  Probably not 
worth persuing.

<cfqueryparam cfsqltype="cf_sql_integer" value='1,2' list="yes">
throws an error for two many paramters.  
The same thing happens with cf_sql_varchar.
```

As stated earlier, I can pass the list as a string, but that seems like a bit of a hack.  Is there a way to pass the list of integers as a list of integers?

Comment: Passing them as a varchar is a mess. You will have to then parse them back into the integers which is not good. You might want to take a look at using table valued parameters instead. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb510489.aspx

Comment: If you're worried about parsing them back as ints, you could use XML also and enforce types with a schema. Although just for my two cents, I use delimited lists all the time in conjunction with a good splitter function. That seems like it invites less headache than TVPs. Again, IMHO.

Comment: I don't know about coldfusion,  but from the sql perspective a table valued parameter is the way to go.

Comment: @Xedni there are SO many awful splitters out there and no matter how you slice it the best approach is to not force sql to split values. That being said there are time when it is ok but as a general rule you should avoid passing around delimited strings. Here is a great article about splitting strings. http://sqlperformance.com/2012/07/t-sql-queries/split-strings

Comment: Consider the XML based approach outlined in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19213814/select-in-on-more-than-2100-values/19213848#19213848 . It works for stored procedures too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

rodmunera's answer has the correct general idea.  Here is how I finally got it to work.

In sql server, I started with this:

```
CREATE  TYPE pt.IntegerTableType AS TABLE 
( integerIN int);
grant execute on type::pt.IntegerTableType to theAppropriateRole
```

Then I changed by stored proc to this:

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[Dan] 
@numbers pt.IntegerTableType readonly
AS
BEGIN
SET NOCOUNT ON;
select 1 record 
where 1 in (select integerIN from @numbers) 
END
```

The Coldfusion code is this:

```
<cfset numbers = "1,2">
<cfquery name="abcd" datasource="ClinicalDataDev">
declare @dan as pt.IntegerTableType

insert into @dan
select null 
where 1 = 2
<cfloop list="#numbers#" index="number">
union
select <cfqueryparam cfsqltype="cf_sql_integer" value="#number#">
</cfloop>

exec dbo.Dan @dan
</cfquery>
<cfdump var="#abcd#">
```

Answer (score 7):

As other commenters mentioned before, passing table-valued parameters is the way to go. This will require you to change the input in the SP to take a table input and in your query you can do

```
<cfquery>
    CREATE TABLE @temp (usedID int)
    INSERT INTO @temp 
        (usedID)
        VALUES
        (1)
        ,(2)

    exec dbo.Dan @temp
</cfquery>
```

You may have to change the way you pass your parameters to the SP, but this is the general idea.

Comment: So far, I've given you a vote.  If you want credit for the answer, fix the sql server syntax inside your cfquery tag.  See my answer as a reference.