# How to pass multiple integer values in one parameter in SQL Server

Tags: sql, t-sql, sql-server-2014

I am in the process of producing a report in SSRS and trying to add a check in to say when this parameter equals this value then display these values, but because the parameter is an integer and I can't pass multiple integer values into the one parameter.

How can I do this?

Here is example of what I am trying to do:

```
DECLARE @EntityGroupID INT
SET @EntityGroupID = 741

IF @EntityGroupID = 741
BEGIN 
     SET @EntityGroupID= 3097,3098,3099,3100,3101,3125
END 

SELECT * 
FROM tEntityGroup
WHERE ID in (@EntityGroupID)
```

Comment: Can't you change your type to `varchar`?

Comment: Write a stored procedure that accepts a Table-Valued Parameter.  Put all the programming logic into the stored procedure.  Use SSRS to display the results.  Here is an example of using a TVP with a stored procedure.  Ignore the Cold Fusion stuff.  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30108973/pass-list-of-integers-to-stored-procedure

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why not just use two `SELECT` statements. If you already have your control flow, just use it to do the `SELECT`, e.g.

```
DECLARE @EntityGroupID INT
SET @EntityGroupID = 741

IF @EntityGroupID = 741
BEGIN 
    SELECT * 
    FROM    tEntityGroup
    WHERE   ID IN (3097,3098,3099,3100,3101,3125);
END 
ELSE
BEGIN
    SELECT  * 
    FROM    tEntityGroup
    WHERE   ID = @EntityGroupID;
END
```

Or if you really want to do it with a single select, then use a table variable:

```
DECLARE @EntityGroupID INT
SET @EntityGroupID = 741

DECLARE @Entities TABLE (ID INT NOT NULL);
INSERT @Entities (ID) 
SELECT  @EntityGroupID
WHERE   @EntityGroupID != 741
UNION ALL
SELECT  ID
FROM    (VALUES (3097),(3098),(3099),(3100),(3101),(3125)) t (ID)
WHERE   @EntityGroupID = 741;

SELECT  * 
FROM    tEntityGroup
WHERE   ID in (SELECT ID FROM @Entities);
```

Answer (score 1):

Pass it as table variable like

```
declare @tbl table(EntityGroupID int);

insert into @tbl
select 3097
union
select 3098
union
select 3099
```

Then you can just say

```
SELECT * 
FROM tEntityGroup
WHERE ID in (select EntityGroupID from @tbl);
```

Comment: Thanks @Rahul the issue I have is when the user selects a Entity Group that is not EntityGroupID 741 then I need to display the group they select

Comment: I didn't get you; can you show an example. Your posted code doesn't make much sense to me.

Answer (score 0):

You can first create a table variable with `ID,Value` pair as:

```
DECLARE @EntityGroup TABLE(Id INT, VALUE VARCHAR(50))
INSERT INTO @EntityGroup VALUES (741,null)

IF (SELECT Id FROM @EntityGroup) = 741
BEGIN 
     update @EntityGroup SET VALUE = '3097,3098,3099,3100,3101,3125' WHERE Id  = 741
END
```

and then we can extract the data as required:

```
SELECT * 
FROM tEntityGroup
WHERE ID in 
(
SELECT LTRIM(RTRIM(m.n.value('.[1]','varchar(8000)'))) AS EntityGroupID
FROM
(
SELECT CAST('<XMLRoot><RowData>' + REPLACE(VALUE,',','</RowData><RowData>') + '</RowData></XMLRoot>' AS XML) AS x
FROM   @EntityGroup
)t
CROSS APPLY x.nodes('/XMLRoot/RowData')m(n)
)
```

Comment: This is needlessly complicated and inefficient.