# How to manipulate comma-separated list in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, xml

I have a list of values such as

```
1,2,3,4...
```

that will be passed into my SQL query.

I need to have these values stored in a table variable. So essentially I need something like this:

```
declare @t (num int)
insert into @t values (1),(2),(3),(4)...
```

Is it possible to do that formatting in SQL Server? (turning 1,2,3,4... into (1),(2),(3),(4)...

Note: I can not change what those values look like before they get to my SQL script; I'm stuck with that list. also it may not always be 4 values; it could 1 or more.

Edit to show what values look like: under normal circumstances, this is how it would work:

```
select t.pk 
from a_table t
where t.pk in (#place_holder#)
```

`#placeholder#` is just a literal place holder. when some one would run the report, #placeholder# is replaced with the literal values from the filter of that report:

```
select t.pk 
from a_table t
where t.pk in (1,2,3,4) -- or whatever the user selects
```

`t.pk` is an `int`

note: doing

```
declare @t as table (
num int
)

insert into @t values (#Placeholder#)
```

does not work.

[image]

Comment: The following answer shows a way to do this with a table-valued function: http://stackoverflow.com/a/5401777/13087

Comment: This shows you how to use Table Valued Parameters http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30108973/pass-list-of-integers-to-stored-procedure

Comment: whats being passed to my sql script literally looks like 1,2,3,4  . its not a string, if I could convert that to a string, then yes, these answers would work.

Comment: What data type is that 'thing' being passed into your script?  In other words, how do you declare it in your script?

Comment: In this answer I added up some nice [tricks you can do with XML and string values](http://stackoverflow.com/a/33658220/5089204). Go to the "Dynamic IN" section. Hope this helps.

Comment: @Just_Some_Guy - we really need to see how 1,2,3,4 is accepted into your script.  It must have some kind of data type definition.

Comment: @devlincarnate Its coming from a filter on a report from a webserver. I have no access to change how those parameters are passed through to my script. when it gets to my script those values would be interpreted as Ints in a normal circumstance.  This is one of the few times that method will not work.

Comment: @Just_Some_Guy - is this script a stored procedure?  a parameterized query?  or what?

Comment: And without a data type, you are going to be out of luck.  SQL requires a known data type in order to operate on a value.

Comment: @Just_Some_Guy - Are you able to do something like this?  `DECLARE @test VARCHAR(10) = '#placeholder#'` ?

Comment: I see what your trying to say; but if I type out '#placeholder#' in the script, I'll end up with '1','2','3','4' and not '1,2,3,4'.

Comment: @Just_Some_Guy - then can't you just do :  `insert into @t values (#placeholder#)` ?

Comment: Search the Internet for fn_split

Comment: Hi @Just_Some_Guy, Thx for marking my answer as accepted! Do you have a reason, not to vote my answer up? Might be you are not aware of the fact, that accepting and voting are two separate steps. Acceptance is great to mark a question as closed and votes are greate as they are a measurement tool for quality and bound to *tag badges* and privileges... Happy Coding!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your description is a bit ridicuolus, but you might give this a try:

Whatever you mean with this

> I see what your trying to say; but if I type out '#placeholder#' in the script, I'll end up with '1','2','3','4' and not '1,2,3,4'

I assume this is a string with numbers, each number between single qoutes, separated with a comma:

```
DECLARE @passedIn VARCHAR(100)='''1'',''2'',''3'',''4'',''5'',''6'',''7''';
SELECT @passedIn; -->: '1','2','3','4','5','6','7'
```

Now the variable `@passedIn` holds exactly what you are talking about
I'll use a dynamic SQL-Statement to insert this in a temp-table (declared table variable would not work here...)

```
CREATE TABLE #tmpTable(ID INT);

DECLARE @cmd VARCHAR(MAX)=
'INSERT INTO #tmpTable(ID) VALUES (' + REPLACE(SUBSTRING(@passedIn,2,LEN(@passedIn)-2),''',''','),(') + ');';

EXEC (@cmd);

SELECT * FROM #tmpTable;
GO

DROP TABLE #tmpTable;
```

### UPDATE 1: no dynamic SQL necessary, all ad-hoc...

You can get the list of numbers as derived table in a CTE easily. 
This can be used in a following statement like `WHERE SomeID IN(SELECT ID FROM MyIDs)` (similar to [this: dynamic IN section](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33658220/5089204) )

```
    WITH MyIDs(ID) AS
    (
        SELECT A.B.value('.','int') AS ID
        FROM
        ( 
        SELECT CAST('<x>' + REPLACE(SUBSTRING(@passedIn,2,LEN(@passedIn)-2),''',''','</x><x>') + '</x>' AS XML) AS AsXml
        ) as tbl
        CROSS APPLY tbl.AsXml.nodes('/x') AS A(B)
    )
    SELECT * FROM MyIDs
```

### UPDATE 2:

And to answer your question exactly:

With this following the CTE

```
insert into @t(num)
SELECT ID FROM MyIDs
```

... you would actually get your declared table variable filled - if you need it later...