# Insert comma seperated float and varchar string into a temporary table

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-insert

I have a string with values:

```
 @value = 'e65.89,f34.yy,sw21.67,aqw21,g45.g4'
```

I need to insert this string as individual rows into a temporary table.

like:

```
     VALUES
     e65.89
     f34.yy
     sw21.67 
     aqw21
     g45.g4
```

I Tried this code,it works fine with integer values but when a float or varchar value is given it shows error:

**code:**

```
CREATE TABLE #Temp (SNo INT IDENTITY(1,1),Code VARCHAR(max))

     Declare @value varchar(max)
     set @value = 'e65.89,f34.yy,sw21.67,aqw21,g45.g4'
    DECLARE @InsertStatement varchar(max) = 'insert into #Temp values ('+REPLACE(@value ,',','),(')+');';
    EXEC (@InsertStatement);

    SELECT * FROM #Temp;
```

**Error:**

```
Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 1
Incorrect syntax near 'e'.
```

Comment: Starting with SQL Server 2016 there is `STRING_SPLIT`. With lower versions you will find tons of examples here...

Comment: You need to quote strings.  You can't insert the values `(e65.89,f34.yy,sw21.67,aqw21,g45.g4)`...  Instead you need to insert the values `('e65.89','f34.yy','sw21.67','aqw21','g45.g4')`

Comment: One hint about the linked question: This is rather old, so are the answers. It is a good idea to sort them and search for the newer ones... Your own code would work if you simply wrap your values with quotes `'e65.89'`.

Comment: @Shnugo but i cant find my answers in surfing

Comment: I feel like I saw this exact question yesterday or Sunday, but the post has since been deleted.

Comment: @MatBailie   wrapping the values with  quotes will work but data's in values variable  is filled dynamically using an stored procedure with comma delimiter

Comment: @Larnu that question is not specific

Comment: @ASHWANT, [read this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/37331465/5089204), it is almost exactly the same as yours...

Comment: @ASHWANT - Your data is built using a call to `REPLACE()`, and can be quoted in there.  If you must use this method, you really should understand how to use it.  It's massively open to SQL Injection Attacks.  Even if you're not open to attacks *(the data could be machine generated)*, if the data ever includes quotes, you need to escape them.  Don't do this.  Really, don't do this.

Comment: @MatBailie ok now what to do ?

Comment: Use `STRING_SPLIT` if on 2016 onwards, or the `UPDATE1` or `UPDATE2` from @Shnugo's answer *(linked in a comment above)*.  Splitting the string isn't going to result in problems.  Embedding data in Dynamic SQL in this way is what's dangerous *(`sp_exectesql` allows passing parameters for exactly that reason.)*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try wrapping the values you are inserting with `''` (single quote marks)

```
CREATE TABLE #Temp (SNo INT IDENTITY(1,1),Code VARCHAR(max))

Declare @value varchar(max)
set @value = 'e65.89,f34.yy,sw21.67,aqw21,g45.g4'
DECLARE @InsertStatement varchar(max) = 'insert into #Temp values (''' + 
REPLACE(@value ,',','''),(''')+ '''' + ');';
EXEC (@InsertStatement);

SELECT * FROM #Temp;
```

Comment: I tried this code only table is created values is not been inserted

Comment: When I run this code on my side, the table is created and all values are inserted. Try to do a PRINT @InsertStatement to see where your insert statement is breaking

Comment: When using PRINT @InsertStatement, your insert should display something like insert into #Temp values ('e65.89'),('f34.yy'),('sw21.67'),('aqw21'),('g45.g4');

Comment: i tried it with  print statement too. still same result  while executing it shows 5 rows affected but It doesnt insert it in my table. It shows :(5 row(s) affected)
insert into #Temp values ('e65.89'),('f34.yy'),('sw21.67'),('aqw21'),('g45.g4');

Comment: If it shows 5 rows affected then it inserted into your table. Do you get nothing back when selecting from the temp table? Also make sure that you drop the temp table by using drop table #Temp before you run the statement again

Comment: i dropped the table before executing it shows 5 rows affected but selecting the table displays nothing except the column name.

Comment: Silly question, you did remember to replace the PRINT statement with EXEC again? When I copy and paste the exact code in my answer I can definitely insert and select the values

Comment: yep i got it @user65439  i didnt select the table in which i inserted

Comment: Glad you got it sorted