# CFML & SQL - Performance Increase?

Tags: sql, performance, coldfusion, cfml

### Brief Overview

Okay, so I've written a query that will filter some products, however, I need to try and further tweak this query to allow for even more filters. I've **kinda** done that, however, it takes twice as long, I mean it takes about 5+ seconds for the page to load and be rendered completely, which isn't good enough in my opinion. I mean it works, but it's just too slow for commercial release.

**I'm assuming** it's so much slower with the function I've copied in below **but sadly** I'm not sure how else I could do this? - I can't think of a way where I could write a query that would essentially eliminate the need to having to use the function I've written.

**I'm guessing**, the best way would be to somehow merge the two queries together, plus another one for other filters that don't work for the current one I have in place? - I'm not totally sure.

**So anyway, here's some code**:-

---

### The Initial Query

```
<cfset row = 0>

...

<cfquery name="query" datasource="ds">
    DECLARE @st TABLE (ID int, z varchar(50))
    DECLARE @tc int

    <cfloop array="#refineArr#" index="x">
    <cfset row ++>
        <cfoutput>
            INSERT INTO @st VALUES ('#IDArr[row]#', '#x#')
        </cfoutput>
    </cfloop>

    SELECT @tc = COUNT(DISTINCT ID) 
    FROM @st
    SELECT tbl.code
    FROM Table1 tbl

    INNER JOIN @st T 
    ON T.ID = tbl.ID 
    AND tbl.V = T.z

    INNER JOIN Table2 tbl2
    ON tbl.ID = tbl2.ID

    WHERE tbl.code IN (<cfqueryparam list="yes" value="#valuelist(getallcodes.code)#">)
    GROUP BY tbl.code
    HAVING COUNT(tbl.ID) = @tc
</cfquery>
```

Just to clarify, this query works just fine, no issues at all. The two arrays are just generated prior to this query, the IDarr array is just an array of **all** ID's that are within a certain category, then the refineArr array is just generated depending on what refinements the user has input. - They're both forced to be the same length so it never tries to get index 'x' for one array when that index doesn't exist.

**And** as you may have guessed, the line 'getallcodes.code', that just gets all codes for all products that **should** show under a certain cat/sub-cat, etc.

---

### Next Part

Okay, so with this next part, due to the different **kinds** of filters, I need to allow for ranges to occur, dates and measurements too. However, ignore the measurements part for now, turns out that the data stored in the database is all screwed up for the measurements.

I originally tried to create a function, it works, but it's not that fast, and to run call the function, I originally wrote this:

```
<cfset ranges = ['Months','Period','SMonths']>
<cfset tc = 0>
<cfset tempQ = query>

...

<cfloop array="#ranges#" index="i">
    <cfset tc ++>
    <cfif i contains 'month' or i contains 'period'>
        <cfset tempQ = rangesFnc(tempQ, Int(tc), ToString(i))>
    </cfif>
</cfloop>
```

---

### The Function Itself

Just keep in mind, I haven't yet finished writing this function, I know it's still a little bit messy, and as for the arrays, they're honestly just a collection of some variables that are critical for working out additional refinements.

```
<cffunction name="rangesFnc">
    <cfargument name="q" type="query" required="true">
    <cfargument name="i" type="numeric" required="true">
    <cfargument name="s" type="string" required="true">

    <cfset minArr = '#minf#,
                    #minh#,
                    #minh2#,
                    #minm#,
                    #mins#'>

    <cfset maxArr = '#maxf#,
                    #maxh#,
                    #maxh2#,
                    #maxm#,
                    #maxs#'>

    <cfset min = listGetAt(minArr, i)>
    <cfset max = listGetAt(maxArr, i)>

    <cfquery name="tempq" datasource="ds">
        WITH q AS (
            SELECT DISTINCT tbl.code,

            CASE
                WHEN tbl.V = 'January' THEN 1
                WHEN tbl.V = 'February' THEN 2
                WHEN tbl.V = 'March' THEN 3
                WHEN tbl.V = 'April' THEN 4
                WHEN tbl.V = 'May' THEN 5
                WHEN tbl.V = 'June' THEN 6
                WHEN tbl.V = 'July' THEN 7
                WHEN tbl.V = 'August' THEN 8
                WHEN tbl.V = 'September' THEN 9
                WHEN tbl.V = 'October' THEN 10
                WHEN tbl.V = 'November' THEN 11
                WHEN tbl.V = 'December' THEN 12
                ELSE 0
            END AS xdate

            FROM Table1 tbl
            INNER JOIN Table2 tbl2
            ON tbl.ID = tbl2.ID

            WHERE tbl2.name LIKE <cfqueryparam value="%#s#%">
            AND tbl.code IN (<cfqueryparam value="#valueList(q.code)#" list="yes">)
        )

        SELECT code 
        FROM q

        WHERE xdate <= <cfqueryparam value="#Int(max)#">
        AND xdate >= <cfqueryparam value="#Int(min)#"> 
    </cfquery>  

    <cfreturn tempq>
</cffunction>
```

---

### Finally

I'd like to apologies for any syntax highlighting issues, as well as the fact that it's a bit messy. In addition to the fact that I've got to leave a lot of info out. The source code itself looks **very** different, but that's deliberate, I'm just copying a **dummy** example here, as it's a part of my responsibility to ensure that I don't expose too much information about the structure of the web page I'm working on, silly I know, but rules are rules.

I've also only added functions like 'Int()' or 'ToString()' to **ensure** that it works as expected, that's it, nothing more, nothing less, it's probably not even needed realistically speaking.

Comment: What version of SQL?

Comment: I believe it's SQL Server 2008. I can't currently check at this very moment in time.

Comment: You are selecting everything in the inner query then filtering by date  (where xdate >= ...) why not simply add "WHERE tbl.V <= #int(max)#" ?

Comment: It needs both the min and the max, as it's a range. But that aside, I've done it like this because I have to do the case scenario, and I just find it nicer and more readable like that. - I don't know if it's the best way to do it, I'm still a junior, but I personally think it's easier to read. 

When you say inner query, I'm assuming you mean sub query? - I'm honestly only asking as I've never heard anyone call a sub query an inner query. Best just clarify any potential confusion! :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is more of a comment, but it is too long.

I really don't like the `<cfloop>` to load a temp table. Your SQL Server will not be able to cache the query and it will have to reparse it every time. I have similar issues with the `#valuelist(getallcodes.code)#`

I would rather that the multi value parameters have there data pulled via something that never changes.

```
<!--- Generate XML of data --->


<cfquery>
DECLARE @st TABLE (ID int, z varchar(50))
DECLARE @tc int
DECLARE @xmlIDArr xml = <cfqueryparam value="#xmlIDarr#">

INSERT INTO @st
SELECT tbl.Col.value('id', 'int'), tbl.Col.value('z', 'varchar(50)')
FROM    @xmlIDArr.nodes('/data') tbl(Col)S


SELECT @tc = COUNT(DISTINCT ID) 
FROM @st
  SELECT tbl.code
  FROM Table1 tbl

  INNER JOIN @st T 
  ON T.ID = tbl.ID 
  AND tbl.V = T.z
</cfquery>
```

For an additional example: [Select IN on more than 2100 values](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19213814/select-in-on-more-than-2100-values)

Comment: I'll also echo what James said. That's a pretty cool use of XML.

Comment: I totally agree, it's not a nice way to do it, I don't even approve of doing it this way, I know it's not ever going to be as fast as what it COULD be. But sadly, I've been told I MUST do it this way, and I'm not going to argue with my boss or the senior developers! :') 

It does KINDA have to be re-parsed all the time (I THINK) due to the fact that there's just such an insane amount of variations of items to be returned and the filters that can be applied to a single item alone. The structure of the data is a little messy, it's far from optimized to say the least...

Comment: Either way, I've improved the performance dramatically, I'm now able to render the page and get it back to the browser in under a single second. Server side, it takes about 0.33s, worst I see it perform now is about 0.75s. It's not too bad, considering the amount of data being returned.

Comment: Look up SQL Server missing index DMV and it will help find some areas that can be further improved.

Comment: I sure as hell will! Thank you! :) 

Finally, I'm debating whether or not to actually use this application with ajax, now that I've made the back-end relatively quick enough for release, there doesn't SEEM to be any major bugs, etc.... 

What would your opinion be on the matter? - It is a lot of information to POST, and my boss seems to think that a LOT of people will be interacting with this page. - Worst case scenario, no ajax (or any pretty animation effects related to the change in content)? 

This form may just be the biggest form I've ever actually had to work with.

Comment: That is a huge question, so let me give my short answer. Every app I build, I add in the JavaScript to cleaning AJAX in Bootstrap modals and Bootstrap tabs. That way as soon as I have a page this large, I can start modal-ing and tabbing to keep things reasonable. I also like using jQuery Datatables, and just pushing over JSON data. Put as much work as possible on the browser.

Answer (score 2):

Some code review points here (and it's an answer because that formats a bit prettier than a comment):

**Initial Query**

1) Move the row variable inside the query and scope it. `<cfset row = 0>` before the query is just asking for trouble.

2) Move your `INSERT` outside of the loop. SQL 2008 can INSERT multiple values. No need to hit the database multiple times.

```
INSERT INTO @st 
VALUES
<cfloop array="#refineArr#" index="x">
    <cfset row++>
    <cfoutput>('#IDArr[row]#','#x#')</cfoutput>
    <cfif row LT ArrayLen(refineArr)>,</cfif>
</cfloop>
```

3) I don't know what the rest of the cf page looks like, but my gut feeling is that the cfquery can be refactored to be a single SELECT without the need for the temp @st table variable.

**Next Part**

Without seeing more of the code, I'm not sure how this can best be optimized. Can there be multiple filters at the same time (ie filtering by `Months and Periods`?

1) Scoping again. There are lots of loose variables here. Some may not be necessary.

2) Is the loop necessary here? Again without more code, I don't know what its purpose is.

3) In your loop, `i contains month or i contains period` is a lot of extra parsing of the value in `i`, and it may not always return what's expected. As written, it will return `SMonths` also.

4) Im assuming `tempQ=query` is just a copy of the First Part query, correct? Is this needed?

**The Function Itself**

1) `minArr` and `maxArr` >> Will the arrays be passed into the function? Or will the `minf, minh....` variables be passed in? They shouldn't be accessed from outside the function. You should be able to run the function completely by itself (and it should probably be its own CFC).

2) They are named like they are arrays, but they contain lists. The names should be consistent with their intent.

3) You rename a variable to `tempq` and set it to the query from earlier, then inside the function create another query named `tempq`. This could get confusing as to which `tempq` you are trying to access if used further down the page.

4) What is the datatype of `Table1.V`? Can you just use a SQL function to return a number for the date name?

5) In your `WHERE` clause, you use `tbl2.name LIKE....`. This should be moved up into the `INNER JOIN` for `Table2`. `INNER JOIN Table2 tbl2 ON tbl.ID = tbl2.ID AND tbl2.name LIKE ()

6) I don't think you need the CTE in this query. You're building out `xdate` only to filter the CTE by it. Add the entire block to the `WHERE` clause.

**Finally**

I've spent almost 2 decades working in proprietary or stricter environments, so I totally understand the need to protect the application source. It can be frustrating, but it's a necessary evil sometimes. I got a bit more wordy here than I intended, but I hope it actually helps. As I said earlier, without knowing a little more about the intent of your application, I can only hope that I've steered you down the right path, and I hope my suggestions have made at least a slight improvement in performance.

Good luck.